# Offset Animated character after applying animation

Tags: unity, animation, fbx, cinemachine

I have 2 FBXs in my project. They are identically named - top to bottom - in their respective FBX hierarchies. When I bring them both into unity, *FBX A* is T-Posed & *FBX B* has an Animation within it as it has been exported from Maya. I import both *FBX A* and *FBX B* into Unity and change the *Animation Type* to *Humanoid*, change the *Avatar Definition* to *Create From This Model*. I then want to apply the animation from FBX B to FBX A by placing the FBX A in the scene, then dragging FBX A onto the *Timeline* and creating an *Animation Track* I then go into the project and drag the *Animation from FBX B* to the *Animation Track of FBX A*.

When this is done I set the *Animation* to *Remove Start Offset*.

FBX A now has the same animation as FBX B - and can be seen doing the same exact motion **However, FBX A is now slightly offset from FBX B** when you play both the animations in the scene, you can see that FBX B is slightly offset from FBX A.

Can anyone account for this strange behaviour?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the offset you're seeing? It's unclear to me whether you're describing a translational, rotational, or temporal offset, or maybe a combination of all three. If you can't show it to us with your real assets for confidentiality reasons, consider reproducing the problem with simple example assets that you *can* show.

Comment: I have further tested this and concluded this must be a bug, as when I set the *Avatar Definition* of FBX A (T-Pose) to *copy the avatar from FBX B (exported with animation)* and then  set the *Avatar Definition* on FBX A to *Create from this Model* , there is no offset seen.

Comment: Sounds like something to report to the Unity dev team then. Is there anything you still need from this Q&A post?